# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: data.subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, angular12

Course-Tracker-component.ts

```
students: Student[];

private async getStudents(){
this.students = [];
const data = (await this.studentsService.getStudents());


data.subscribe(
  studentsResponse =>{
    studentsResponse.students.map(s => {
      this.students.push({
        id: s.id,
        first_Name: s.first_Name,
        last_Name:s.last_Name,
        middle_Name:s.middle_Name,
        gender:s.gender,
        dob:s.dob,
        address:s.address,
        email:s.email
      });
    });
  });

  console.log(this.students);
}
```

(Student-Service.ts)

```
export class StudentsService extends HttpclientService{
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
}

public getStudents():Observable<StudentsResponse>{
    return this.get(UniversityAPIUrl.GET_STUDENTS);}
```

(httpclient-service.ts)

```
protected get(relativeUrl: string){
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.baseUrl + relativeUrl, { headers:this.getHeaders()});
}
```

(Student.ts)

```
export class Student{
id: number;
first_Name: string;
last_Name:string;
middle_Name:string;
gender:string;
dob:Date;
address:string;
email:string;
}
```

(Student-response.ts)

```
export class StudentsResponse{
    students: Student[];
}
```

In my course-tracker-component.ts I can view the data by saying (`console.log(data)`). However, I cannot grab the values in the data observable object. All I would like to do is take the result of `const data` and push it into my empty student array which is comprised of student objects.

Answer (score 0):

`.toPromise()` actually converts the observable returned by the original `httpClient.get()` method to a promise by subscribing to the observable and resolving the promise with a value once the event occoured. That value is a json or text value, not an observable you can subscribe to. This is why you are getting that error message.

If I were you, I would remove the call to the `toPromise()` method and work with only the observable.

By the way, you can simply *console.log* the object on you are trying to call a method when you see this kind of error messages, so that you can see the actual value; whether it is a promise, observable, the actual data or other...

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').   I have done what you asked and now this is the error